# Can't retrieve contacts from a locked HTC 300

Tags: adb, contacts, htc-desire, locked-out

So... here's the story. My father had his **HTC Desire 300** for ages and he stored all of his contacts on the phone, not on the SIM card. One day, my unreasonably curious mother wanted to unlock it and she locked the phone because she attempted to guess the pattern way too many times.

It would've been easy to unlock it if only my father knew his gmail account info. I tried all sorts of combinations, he's an older fella so I figured I could maybe brute force it, but to no avail.

To make things even worse, the phone isn't even rooted. He got a new phone, but he wanted me to salvage his photos and contacts. I managed to pull all the photos using adb, but I just can't find a way to extract his contacts. I tried everything but I always bump into issues with permissions, since the phone isn't rooted and there's no custom recovery and the bootloader is locked.

Any ideas? :/

Comment: No backup for Gmail account ? Like secondary email he may have set up - check that and ADB can't help with contacts

Comment: Nothing, he doesn't even remember the account name, I tried some possible canditates, but I only ended up retrieving his other account. I even tried my mother's accounts, since the phone belonged to her for a while, but nothing...

Comment: If Google voice was activated [there is a chance](https://itstillworks.com/finding-gmail-account-associated-phone-number-32515.html)

Comment: Long shot - Google his telephone number and hope search results include his email